# Как сделать выбор всех элементов списка recyclerView через его адаптер?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня в приложении есть список основанный на `recyclerView` у которого есть свой адаптер. Данный список находится в фрагменте который находится в свою очередь на активити с контейнером. Совсем недавно ввел понятие редактирования списка, в нем у меня возле каждого элемента списка появляется появляется чекбокс, и при выборе хотя бы одного бокса у меня появляется кнопка на активити где висит контейнер с фрагментом, а если все чеки снять то из режима редактирования мы выходим. Видел в многих программах что есть есть функция выбора всех элементов списка, но не очень понятно как это сделать. То что это нужно будет делать в цикле то это и так понятно, но не понятно как и где его сделать. Для того чтобы выбрать все элементы я хочу сделать слушатель на выбор одного отдельного чекбокса который находится за пределами списка в фрагменте. Но вот что дальше делать я не очень понимаю.

Вот как я себе это представляю: мы на нашем фрагменте чекаем наш бокс и у нас вызывается функция в адаптере которая делает переход в режим редактирования и отмечает у каждого элемента списка его чекбокс. То есть в этой функции в адаптере нужно запускать цикл, но вот что дальше делать я не могу понять. Может сделать все через интерфейс, но тоже не понятно как именно.  И не могу понять где размещать слушатель на выбор главного чекбокса, в фрагменте или в активити где висит этот фрагмент.

Не очень понял какой код выложить, поэтому выкладываю тот который у меня есть для выбора одного чекбокса в режиме редактирования:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    set.add(message.getId());
                } else {
                    set.remove(message.getId());
                    if (getChecked().isEmpty()) {
                        editMode = false;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

вот в адаптере функция для включения режима редактирования в адаптере:

```
private void setEditMode() {
        if (!editMode) {
            editMode = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

если у меня `editMode = true` то у меня в `onBindViewHolder` стоит условие:

```
if (editMode) {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stateListener.check(1);

        }
```

вот интерфейс:

```
public interface StateListener {
    void check(int k);
}
```

может еще что-то нужно добавить в вопрос, скажите пожалуйста, я добавлю, но пока вроде кинул все что есть. Надеюсь этот вопрос уже исследован и имеет ответ.

### UPDATE

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.SenderHolder> {

    private Integer type;
    private ArrayList<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    public static boolean editMode;
    static boolean checkAlll;
    public static boolean clearAllCheck;
    private StateListener stateListener;
    private static HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id";
    private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id";
    private static final String keyDraftMessageId = "draft_message_id";

    ListAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messageList, Context ctx, int type) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.type = type;
    }

    void setListener(StateListener listener) {
        this.stateListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new SenderHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SenderHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);
        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        boolean attachment = message.isAttachment();
        Integer new_one = message.getNewField();
        stateListener.check(0);

        if (checkAlll) {
            checkAll();
            stateListener.check(1);
        }
        if (!checkAlll) {
            stateListener.check(0);
        }

        if (editMode) {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stateListener.check(1);

        } else {
            stateListener.check(0);
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (attachment) {
                holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
                break;
        }

        if (new_one == 1 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message.getSender_name())) {
            holder.tvSubject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.tvFrom.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());


        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                switch (type) {
                    case 0:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyOutboundMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyIncomingMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent.putExtra(ListAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyDraftMessageId, message.getId());
                        break;
                }

                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (message.isCan_delete()) {
                    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                setEditMode();
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (set.contains(message.getId())) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    set.add(message.getId());
                } else {
                    set.remove(message.getId());
                    if (getChecked().isEmpty()) {
                        editMode = false;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                /*List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
                Toast.makeText(ctx, list.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            }
        });
    }


    private void setEditMode() {
        if (!editMode) {
            editMode = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void checkAll() {
        for (Message message : messageList) {
            set.add(message.getId());
        }
    }


    public static HashSet<Integer> getChecked() {
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;
        final ImageView attachIV;
        final CheckBox checkBox;

        SenderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            attachIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clip);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() нужно использовать везде, где был изменен view, иначе чекбоксы у вас будут слетать при прокрутке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтоб у вас выбрались все элементы в списке, вам нужно добавить айдишники всех ваших элементов в ваше множество (set) и вызывать notifyDataSetChanged(). Функция в вашем адаптере:

```
public void checkAll() {
    for (Message message : messages) {
        set.add(message.getId());
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Код главного чекбокса лучше разместить в фрагменте. (Если код относится только к компонентам фрагмента то нет смысла выносить его в Активити)

Comment: возникла довольно интересная ситуация - почему-то не весь список выделяется при выборе главного чекбокса, примерно половину не выбирает

Comment: если проблема осталась то хорошо было бы код адаптера показать

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста, проблема та же и по какой-то не понятной причине у меня при первом нажатии на главный чекбокс не появляется выбор у всех элементов списка, а вот при втором нажатии уже все элементы выбраны

Comment: У вас в коде очень много ошибок. private static HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

Comment: а где именно ошибки? эта строка которую вы указали в своем комментарии тоже ошибочна?

Comment: Непонятно зачем set статическая переменная (возможно стоит почитать о static). Вы не так использовали мой ответ :( . В checkAll() должен быть notifyDataSetChanged() и методу нужен модификатор доступа public, и обращение должно идти к нему через объект адаптера как реакция на какое-то действие. Нужно почитать про работу Recyclerview и Adapter, метод onBindViewHolder вызывается для изменения каждого айтема списка отдельно и вы в нем каждый раз делаете checkAll() что вообще не правильно. И вот вам пример https://medium.com/@maydin/multi-and-single-selection-in-recyclerview-d29587a7dee2

Comment: я вот почитал то что вы мне сбросили, но все-равно не очень понятно в чем у меня проблемы, если можете то объясните поподробнее :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84578/discussion-between---and-andrew-goroshko).